# Adding normal maps to bufferGeometry shapes in THREE

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I'm trying to add normal map (in this case wood texture) to custom part I've created using THREE.BufferGeometry() and vertices.

For this particular part:

```
//edit initially I left out this part while posting. My script sees this folder and gives no errors
const woodPattern = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const woodTexture = woodPattern.load('/textures/wood_pattern.jpg');

const frame_upper_part_geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
const frame_upper_part_positions = [
     0.8,  0.8,  0.95,
    -0.8,  0.8,  0.95,
    -0.8,  0.8,  0.75,

    -0.8,  0.8,  0.75,
     0.8,  0.8,  0.75,
     0.8,  0.8,  0.95,
     
     0.6,  0.6,  0.95,
    -0.6,  0.6,  0.95,
    -0.6,  0.6,  0.75,
 
    -0.6,  0.6,  0.75,
     0.6,  0.6,  0.75,
     0.6,  0.6,  0.95,

     0.8,  0.8,  0.95,
     0.6,  0.6,  0.95,
     0.6,  0.6,  0.75,
     
     0.6,  0.6,  0.75,
     0.8,  0.8,  0.75,
     0.8,  0.8,  0.95,

     -0.8,  0.8,  0.95,
     -0.6,  0.6,  0.95,
     -0.6,  0.6,  0.75,
     
     -0.6,  0.6,  0.75,
     -0.8,  0.8,  0.75,
     -0.8,  0.8,  0.95,

     0.8,  0.8,  0.75,
    -0.8,  0.8,  0.75,
    -0.6,  0.6,  0.75,

    -0.6,  0.6,  0.75,
     0.6,  0.6,  0.75,
     0.8,  0.8,  0.75,
];
frame_upper_part_geometry.setAttribute( 
    'position', 
    new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( frame_upper_part_positions, 3 ) 
);
frame_upper_part_geometry.computeVertexNormals();
const frame_material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({normalMap:woodTexture})
frame_material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
frame_material.color = new THREE.Color(0x654321)
const frame_upper_part = new THREE.Mesh(frame_upper_part_geometry, frame_material)
scene.add(frame_upper_part)
```

I get no errors, however adding normal map doesnt seem to change a thing, even though if I added it the same way with predefined geometry in THREE itself, it should work. Am I missing something?

[result I'm getting, no errors, however effects of normal map are not present.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOQF6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are not generating any texture coordinates for the custom geometry. Hence, applying textures won't work as expected. Texture coordinates are stored in the called `uv` buffer attribute.